# 2 select2 in a form, one has added maximum selection value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have one form and 2 select2's, I have added an extra class to both one is `.group` and the other is `.systemComponents`, but on the one **(group)** I want a `maximumselectvalue` which isn't working. Both are working but the group one isn't only allowing the select once option.

```
@Html.Partial("_FormElementPartial", new ViewDataDictionary() {
{ "Label", LH.GetText(SystemComponent.TheSystem, "lblForm_System_Components") },
{ "Element", Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedSystemComponentsIds2, Model.AvailableSystemComponents2, new {@class = "js-select2 group textBoxSizeFullWidth textSizeStandard text-input formElement", style = "width:100%"}) },
{ "Info", Html.LocalisedTooltip("ttArticle_SystemComponents", "lblArticleManagement_SystemComponents_ToolTip", SystemComponent.TheSystem) }
})

@Html.Partial("_FormElementPartial", new ViewDataDictionary() {
{ "Label", LH.GetText(SystemComponent.TheSystem, "lblForm_System_Components") },
{ "Element", Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedSystemComponentsIds, Model.AvailableSystemComponents, new {@class = "js-select2 systemComponents textBoxSizeFullWidth textSizeStandard text-input formElement", style = "width:100%"}) },
{ "Info", Html.LocalisedTooltip("ttArticle_SystemComponents", "lblArticleManagement_SystemComponents_ToolTip", SystemComponent.TheSystem) }
})

$('#mdlCreateNewArticle .js-select2').select2({
    }).on('select2:opening', '.group', function (e) {
        maximumSelectionSize: 1;
        if ($('.group').select2('val').length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

So what I'm trying to do is have one call which seems to work fine, but only on `.group` the maximum selection works.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but always happy for comments.

```
if ($('.group-select2').is(':visible')) {
        $('#mdlCreateNewArticle .group').select2({
        }).on('select2:opening', function (e) {
            maximumSelectionSize: 1;
            if ($(this).select2('val').length > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }

$('#mdlCreateNewArticle .systemComponents').select2();
```